# How to download an html webpage containing a filled form as an HTML file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a webpage that contains a form. The user will fill out the form fields on the webpage.

How can I save the webpage as an HTML file that includes the filled-in form fields?

The code below downloads the webpage as an HTML file, but the form fields are empty.

```
<a onClick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)"
   href="#" download="page.html">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the working [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lucasroquilly/pen/wvyxKQY) as the download feature does not work in Stackoverflow's snippet frame.

I just filled the "value" attribute for each input with its own value, then trigger the download.

```js
function download(){
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    inputs[i].setAttribute("value", inputs[i].value);
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.html';
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<input value="" type="text">
<input value="" type="text">
<input value="" type="text">
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
</div>
```